# ctrl+s is required to update the UI while I am using provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an auth screen where i am using `isLogin` boolean... I created a method to change the value of isLogin but it requires ctrl+s or use `SetState()` to change the value and update UI...
here is the Provider class code

```
  bool _isLogin = true;
  bool get isLogin => _isLogin;
  changeAuth(value) {
    _isLogin = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

here I am calling method

```
   TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              auth.changeAuth(
                                  auth.isLogin == true ? false : true);
                           
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              auth.isLogin
                                  ? "Register a new account"
                                  : "Login instead",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  color: Colors.blue),
                            ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `auth` is `Provider`

```
 TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              context.read<ProviderClassName>().changeAuth(
                                  context.read<ProviderClassName>().isLogin == true ? false : true);
                           
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              context.watch<ProviderClassName>().isLogin
                                  ? "Register a new account"
                                  : "Login instead",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  color: Colors.blue),
                            ))
```

Comment: thanks. It's working.... is it the only solution for this issue?

Comment: i"ll accept the answer once time is completed

Comment: no. You can also use `setState()` of `StatefulWidget`. However, since you used `Provider`, you solved the problem by using the Provider.